# Why am I getting "Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user" when attempting to connect?

Tags: php

I can connect to php/myadmin by using the connection string, but if i am trying to connect through my php page, then it's giving the following error.

> Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'bf_cards_user'@'My Server IP' (using password: NO) in /home/blue204/html/download/test_connection.php

Here is my code:

```
$dbCon = mysql_connect('My Server IP', 'bf_cards_user', 'bbeqvfyAwPWECvWs');
if ($dbCon){
    echo "connected";
} else {
    echo "not connected" ;
}
```

Comment: Have you replaced "My Server IP" with your IP address? Usually it is "localhost".

Comment: Funny that it says "using password: NO" although you gave one.

Comment: Yeah, Alex is correct. You don't seem to be using a password yet you are passing one. Make sure you have set a password, as well as replacing "My Server IP" with "localhost" or whatever the IP address is.

Comment: i am using the proper IP address of my database server instead of localhost. as i have mentioned earlier that i can login into the php/myadmin by using the same information. but if i am trying to this connection string than i am unable to connect it.

Comment: what line this error occurs on?

Comment: $dbCon = mysql_connect('My Server IP', 'bf_cards_user', 'bbeqvfyAwPWECvWs');

its showing the error in the above line.

Answer (score 1):

Have you allowed access to the MySQL server for the login/server combination you provide?

```
grant all permissions on *.* 'bf_cards_user'@'My Server IP'
    identified by 'bbeqvfyAwPWECvWs';
flush privileges;
```

Answer (score -3):

You have made two mistakes here. The first mistake is you have passed "My Server IP" as your IP address. This is usually "localhost", but can also be an IP address for your server. Secondly (as pointed out in the comments of your OP), it says there is no password for the database yet you have stated one. You should ensure your database user has a password set.