# can't use the XAMPP CD Collection program

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I just installed XAMPP 1.8.2 for Windows.
I changed security settings for accessing the MySQL db and now that I run CD Collection (under Php in the menu on the left) I get this error:

```
Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\cds.php on line 78
Could not connect to database!
Is MySQL running or did you change the password?
```

So I changed the password yet it's trying to access the db with the user root and no password?
I've read that you have to flush privileges but I'm not sure how I can do that, do I have to access the userlist in phpMyAdmin and update something there?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a duplicate as the answer provided differs from those in your linked thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the password in the cds.php file located at [xampp folder]/htdocs/xampp/cds.php . The credentials need to be filled in on line 5:

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
```

Place your new password between the quotes.
Also do this on line 78:

```
if(!mysql_connect("localhost","root",""))
```

Comment: did that and still getting the same error, I restarted the Apache and MySQL modules.

Comment: You are right; you also need to change the credentials on line 78; `if(!mysql_connect("localhost","root",""))`

Comment: Ok, that worked, thanks.
Please edit your answer so I can mark it as "accepted".
I have a concern though, is this the safest way?
This means that my password is hardcoded into a .php file, isn't it better to change permissions as suggested by the possible duplicate @perdeu posted? ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7635663/why-am-i-getting-warning-mysql-connect-access-denied-for-user-when-attempt )

Comment: Yes the code is a bit ugly, usually a config file is used so the credentials can be changed easily. Such a config file is still a php file, storing credentials in them is fine I think.